# Magento 2 - Customer session lost in controller

Tags: magento2, customer, session

I encountered a strange error while getting customer session in a Controller execute method as below:

```
$resultPage = $this->_resultPageFactory->create();
$this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn(); // return true;
$resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle();
$this->_customerSession->isLoggedIn(); // return false;
```

Why the customer session will be cleared at line 4?

Comment: it's work perfectly. Which version and which mode you use?

Comment: I use v2.0.8 Community Edition

Comment: Could you put the whole controller's code here? It might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The reason of this behavior is the way Magento 2 full page cache works.

Pages in Magento 2 are rendered depersonalized (without any private information) to be cached for all visitors. Private information is later pulled by javascript and private blocks are updated.

For this purpose there are a set of Denationalization plugins introduced, that flush all sessions when rendering starts.

In your case `$resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()` will trigger `\Magento\Framework\View\Page\Config::build()` and further layout XML generation.
The plugin `\Magento\Customer\Model\Layout\DepersonalizePlugin::afterGenerateXml` calls `$this->session->clearStorage()` to prevent private data used during rendering.

Thant's why session is empty after `$resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle();` call.